# Format string to fit pattern in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Say I have a pattern, and a string:

```
String  = "ABCDEF"
Pattern = "%w%w%w - %w%w%w"
```

How can I make `String` match the format of `Pattern`, so it becomes `"ABC - DEF"`?

Comment: `String = String:gsub("()",{[4]=" - "})`

Comment: It is not clear: can you change the pattern? If yes, see Yu's answer. If not, please explain the current scenario in some greater detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub):

```
string.gsub("ABCDEF", "(%w%w%w)(%w%w%w)", "%1 - %2")
```

Note that this would replaces all the occurrences of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There no one to one match beetween string, pattern and capture.
Same capture can be produced by several patterns for same string.
Also if `"%w%w%w - %w%w%w"` in your example is Lua string pattern then
string `"ABC - DEF"` does not match to it. Patterns that match to it can be
`%w%w%w %- %w%w%w` or `%w+%W+%w+` or `%w*%s*.%s*%w*` or several others.
So I suggest define your own subset of rules that you really need and
implement your own function to handle it.